# thrift didn't throw exception when I use a port that is already used by another process

Tags: java, thrift

I use a already used port when constructing TServerSocket, but it didn't throw exception. Is this a thrift known issue or I misuse the API ? Thanks

```
serverTransport = new TServerSocket(this.port);
server = new TThreadPoolServer(
     new TThreadPoolServer.Args(serverTransport).processor(processor));
```

Comment: Apache Thrift supports about 20+ languages. Which one do you use?

Comment: I use java library